# Write Custom c# class to represent the JSON?

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON string for which I need to create the C# class and then parse the entire List in similar format. JSON String contain "0" and "1". I have annotated the class properties with

> [JsonProperty("0")]

but look like its not working.

```
 {
  "draw": 4,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    {
      "0": "Charde",
      "1": "Marshall",
      "2": "Regional Director",
      "3": "San Francisco",
      "4": "16th Oct 08",
      "5": "$470,600",
      "DT_RowId": "row_13"
    },
    {
      "0": "Colleen",
      "1": "Hurst",
      "2": "Javascript Developer",
      "3": "San Francisco",
      "4": "15th Sep 09",
      "5": "$205,500",
      "DT_RowId": "row_9"
    },
    {
      "0": "Dai",
      "1": "Rios",
      "2": "Personnel Lead",
      "3": "Edinburgh",
      "4": "26th Sep 12",
      "5": "$217,500",
      "DT_RowId": "row_20"
    }]
    }
```

Class that I  have tried for this JSON

```
public class UserData
    {
        [JsonProperty("0")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("1")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

       //Having more JSON properites 

        [JsonProperty("DT_RowId")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonValdate
    {
       public string draw { get; set; }
       public int length { get; set; }
       public int start { get; set; }
       public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
       public int recordsTotal { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("data")]
       public UserData[] data { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be that some of **JSON data** cannot be converted to  **UserData Properties**.

Right off the bat, you can see `"DT_RowId": "row_20"` cannot be converted to `long UserId`.

Use **try catch block** outside of conversion, and see the exception.

For example,

```
private string Json
{
    get { 
        return @"
        {
            ""draw"": 4,
            ...
        }"; 
    }
}

try
{
    JsonValdate result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonValdate>(Json);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     // Debug
}
```

## Here is how I test

Since the conversion is not working, do not put all fields at once.

Start with the following working fields. Then add one field at a time.

```
private string Json
{
    get { return @"
        {
        ""draw"": 4,
        ""recordsTotal"": 57,
        ""recordsFiltered"": 57,
        ""data"": [
                {
                    ""0"": ""Charde"",
                    ""1"": ""Marshall""
                },
                {
                    ""0"": ""Colleen"",
                    ""1"": ""Hurst""
                },
                {
                    ""0"": ""Dai"",
                    ""1"": ""Rios""
                }]
        }"; 
    }
}

public class UserData
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class JsonValdate
{
    public string draw { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public UserData[] data { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        JsonValdate result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonValdate>(Json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have converted the UserId in long to string, while Json conversion. It was working fine. I'm not getting "0" and "1" in data array index. thx